# function not recognized in dispatch in redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I try to pass my array in the payload of my udpateDispo () action but it does not recognize the function
I voluntarily removed code to simplify reading,
but basically all my actions work (from my real code) except this one,
I don't understand why the syntax is the same that I used with the others,

I tried other functions that work elsewhere here and they are no longer not recognized why?

```js
export const UPDATE_DISPO = 'UPDATE_DISPO'
export const updateDispo = (dispo) => {
  console.log("selected")
  console.log("this disp", dispo)
  return {
    type: UPDATE_DISPO,
    dispo,

  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

import React from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {updateDispo } from '../../../redux/actions/Action'

   dispo = () => {
    
        let start = 1
        let end = 25
        let go = []

        while(start <  end)  {
          start = start + 1 
          time.push({
          start: start,
          end: end,  
          });
        }
        this.state.disponibilitie = time;
        let dispo = time;
        this.props.udapteDispo(dispo)
      }
      
      class test extends React.Component {
      
       render(){
        
        return(
          
            <div>
            <p> this.props.result </p>
            </div>   
        )
      }
  
      }
      
      
   const mapStateToProps =  (state) => {
    return {
      
        result : state.result,
        
    }
  }
        
  const mapDispatchToProps =  (dispatch) => {

    return {
           
        updateDispo: (dispo) => { dispatch(updateDispo(dispo)) },        
}

  }
export default connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(test)
```

my error is :

typeError:

this.props.udpateDispo
is not a function

Answer (score 1):

Update:

In your `mapDispatchToProps`:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  updateDispo: dispo => {dispatch(updateDispo(dispo))}
})
```

But you try to call `udapteDispo`. Pay attention to naming.

---

You try to call `this.props.udpateDispo` out of `test` component. Out of this component `this.props` doesn't exist.

And edit your `mapDispatchToProps` function:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  updateDispo: dispo => dispatch(updateDispo(dispo))
})
```

Comment: I created another arrow function with another dispath function and it works they are also outside the component

why this one doesn't work?

Comment: @Chahmeldine, first of all this is strange because after you wrapped  ```test``` component to ```connect``` it became a ```container```. In other words he knows about redux, dispatch and store.
Secondly, arrow function doesn't have own scope. It refers to the outer scope. In outer scope doesn't exist ```prop```, only in ```test``` component.